# Vue-Router Programmatically Open Modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a login page that I will re-direct to if a user is not authenticated (via the meta tag auth), and conversely if a user is logged in, will get redirected to home if he/she tries to visit the login page (via the meta tag guest).  The authenticated state is stored in Vuex:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.auth) && 
    !store.state.auth.authenticated) {
  // If user is not authenticated, redirect to login page
    next({
      name: 'Login',
    })
  } else if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.guest) && 
    store.state.auth.authenticated) {
  // If user is authenticated and on guest page, redirect to home
    next({
      name: 'Home',
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

What I would like to do is make my login page a modal instead of a landing page.  I've been able to make a login modal and have it appear when clicking on a button, but is there a way to have vue-router automatically display the modal if a user attempts to go to a link that requires authentication instead of going to a dedicated landing page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood you right, u can call mutation in your state management(u use Vuex as i think) to open model dialog logIn form

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.auth) && 
    !store.state.auth.authenticated) {
  /* If user is not authenticated,
     make action/mutation to the store to open a dialog  
  */
    store.commit('openLogInDialog')
    next(false)
  } else next()
})
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't even think to have the modal listen on the store (I was using locally defined data in the component).

Comment: newbie here could you kindly explain what openLoginDialog is how it ll actually work